# Loading new HTML into Visual Basic web browser

Tags: vb.net, io, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser that on load of the application i have placed html into it

```
webBrowse.Document.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText("\\comp\shared\index.html"))
```

and I am trying to load a new html doc into it once the user selects a certain item from a listbox

```
webBrowse.Document.Write(IO.File.ReadAllText("\\comp\shared\userpage" + user))
```

Note user is the page of a certain user in the format of user[id_num].html

Do I need to do anything else? when the method is called once something is picked the web browser stays on the same page that was up when it loaded.

I am thinking that maybe I need to refresh the screen or redraw it like java I am not sure but I am not that experienced in VB so any help would be helpful.

Comment: The [`Navigate` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably more appropriate

Comment: Would it be formatted the same way?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the second line of code you have listed above is actually running?  Put a break point on it and F5 to debug it and make sure it is running.  Show the code for the listbox--is it set to runat="server" and autopostback="true"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Navigate to allow me to Navigate to the next page without using i/o functions, and changed it to also change input so the map would load.